# Partition with two columns in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, partition

I would like to partition my table within two columns. I have Data like :

```
date       numero   demande     action
01/02/2020  2011-3  1          SUPPRESSION
01/02/2020  2011-3  1          OPPOSITION
01/02/2020  2011-3  1          DATA
01/09/2020  2011-3  1          OPPOSITION
01/09/2020  2011-3  1          SUPPRESSION
01/09/2020  2011-3  1          SUPPRESSION
01/02/2020  2011-3  1          DATA
```

I have more than 20k thousand lines and I would like to partition with date (varchar) and with action.

I tried to to this with Postgresql :

```
CREATE TABLE helloone (date varchar,
                      numero varchar,
                      demande varchar,
                      action varchar)
PARTITION BY RANGE (date,action);
```

But I have no idea on the next step to have the result I need. Thank you !

Comment: 20k thousand - doesn't that mean 20 million?

Comment: Don't store dates in a varchar column, use proper _date_ data type instead.

Comment: Why not a composite index instead?

Comment: Your `CREATE TABLE` will cause an error, because there are no columns named `two` and `four`.

Comment: I can only repeat what jarlh wrote: **never**, ever store DATE values in a `varchar` column. Just don't

Comment: Why do you think you want a range partition over a DATE (!) and a varchar? It sounds as if you want to use sub-partitioning instead. Partition the table by the date value, then partition each partition by the action (or the other way round - depends on how you want to access the data and why you think you need partitioning to begin with)

Comment: @jarlh  I am working with an existent DB that stores data like that

Comment: "I am working with an existent DB that stores data like that"  Then fix it.  Coming up with partitioning schemes probably won't fix the problem.  But fixing the problem will fix the problem.